# How to Pipe Powershell Commands together in C#

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0

I have a set of commands in Powershell 2 where the output of one function is the input to the next function, but in the output of the first function I can select a value from the result, which is to be the input to the next function.

For example with

```
Get-RDUserSession | ? {$_.username -eq "myuser"} | Disconnect-User
```

My example, I am selecting a user called "myuser", and passing this user into a function called Disconnect-User to do something. All works in Powershell, but I would like to be able to replicate this in C# without having to write multiple lines of code.

Is it possible to reproduce this in C# in one line like in Powershell?

Comment: actually, there is two points in your question. 1st: what is the C# equivalent of the powershell function `Get-RDUserSession` and `Disconnect-User`. 2nd is: how can I call these equivalent in one line. I guess that the 1st is actually the question... and its answer is, I bet, far from trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you'd end up with something like (multiline to make it more readable on SO; though I also prefer to format my code like that 'in real life'):

```
GetRDUserSessionMethod().Where(u => u.username == "myuser")
                        .ToList()
                        .ForEach(DisconnectUser);
```

`GetRDUserSessionMethod()` would simply have to return an `IEnumerable<SomeUserClass>`.

`ToList()` is required because MS never decided to have such an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>`, which for various reasons (type safety!) would be a nice addition to the language. It's pretty trivial to write one yourself if you want to avoid doing a `ToList()` each time, quick and dirty example:

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (T element in source)
    { 
        action(element);
    }
}
```

There can be some discussion on whether this is more readable than a regular `foreach { }` statement - probably as many opinions as devs out there. Personally, I don't have an issue with writing code like that.

Comment: Please note though that Get-RDUserSession and Disconnected-User are commands in my Powershell Script which I want to invoke via C# - sorry if I have not made this particular clear

Comment: @Andy5 Doable, but overcomplicated. Basically each call to powershell using C# requires a few lines of code (initializing a `PowerShell` object, feeding it a line+ of script and invoking PS). If your intention is to simply call PS from C#, unless you intend to do some complicated stuff inside the pipe, it might be simpler to simply call the original PS and let it work. TL;DR - PS/C# 'context switch' is a bit complicated, so you probably want to avoid doing it more than once per script.

Answer (score 0):

command1 && command2

Say to restart a service named "XYZ" using c#

net stop "XYZ" && net start "XYZ"

Code Example is,

```
using (Process command = new Process())
{        
    command.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        FileName = CommonStrings.RestartProccesCommand,
        Arguments = COMMAND1 && COMMAND2,
        LoadUserProfile = false,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    };
    command.Start();
    command.WaitForExit(3000);
    exitCode = command.ExitCode;
}
```